# Binding Checkbox with database column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I am binding Checkbox field to database and want to show actual value like if in database it is 1 then checkbox should be ticked in gridview else unchecked. I tried but my code doesn't show avtual value in checkbox, always remain unchecked.

CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid"  Width="450px" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
               <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" />   
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint" OnCheckedChanged="ckboxIsComplaint_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("IsComplaint") %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 106), ' ','/') as RecievingDate
      ,[ToMobileNo]
      ,[FromMobileNo]
      ,[Message],
       [IsComplaint]
      FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
      where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo AND IsComplaint=1
```

Comment: Could you also please post the code where you do the data-binding, in your code behind class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you will get only `true` or `false` then you can use the following, by adding

`Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>'` to the `CheckBox`.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint" OnCheckedChanged="ckboxIsComplaint_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>' />
```

If you are getting `null` value also, then you need to do the `checking` and `unchecking` from C# code in `RowDataBound` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsComplaint" HeaderText="IsComplaint"  SortExpression="IsComplaint" />
```

instead of using

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint"> ............. </asp:TemplateField>
```